# Why is this integral divergent?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, generalized-function

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[1 - y]*DiracDelta[y - 5], {y, 0, 10}]
```

this is divergent integral but this

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[1 - y]*DiracDelta[y - 5], {y, 0, 3}]
```

and this

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[1 - y]*DiracDelta[y - 5], {y, 3, 10}]
```

are convergent, each of the above two equal to zero. What is correct? What do I do if I want following integral?
$$I=\int f(y)\delta(A-y)\delta(y-B)dy$$

$f(y)$ is arbitrary well-behaved function of $y$ and $A$ and $B$ are constants.

Comment: The first integral is NOT divergent, it is simply not evaluated. It looks like MMA does not know the rule: `Integrate[DiracDelta[x-a] DiracDelta[x-b],x] ==  DiracDelta[a-b]`

Comment: @DanielHuber: How about `Integrate[
 DiracDelta[y - 1]*DiracDelta[1 - y]*DiracDelta[y - 5], {y, 0, 10}]` whivh returns the input, but `Integrate[
 DiracDelta[y - 1]*DiracDelta[1 - y]*DiracDelta[y - 5], {y, 0, 3}]` and `Integrate[
 DiracDelta[y - 1]*DiracDelta[1 - y]*DiracDelta[y - 5], {y, 3, 10}]` result in zero? Up to the documentation, the product `DiracDelta[y - 1]*DiracDelta[1 - y]*DiracDelta[y - 5]` is not defined because the supports of `DiracDelta[y-1]` and `DiracDelta[1-y]` are the same set $\{1\}$.

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Is that Dirac delta product well defined when a==b? I believe it is not.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 1):

Daniel Huber suggested in a comment that it's a limitation of `Integrate`. You can report it to WRI, and they might improve `Integrate` in a future release.  For now, the following is a workaround in V12.2.  It is suggested by the OP's observations on what works; namely the suggestion is that if we separate the singular points in the integration intervals, `Integrate` will evaluate.

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[1 - y]*DiracDelta[y - 5], {y, 0, 3, 10}]
(*  0  *)
```

It also works on the general integral, with the assumption that $A<B$; [@DanielLichtblau's comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/241475/why-is-this-integral-divergent/241481#comment609450_241475) suggests why `Integrate` does not evaluate the integral without the assumption:

```
Integrate[
 f[y] DiracDelta[a - y]*DiracDelta[y - b],
 {y, -Infinity, (a + b)/2, Infinity},
 Assumptions -> a < b]
(*  0  *)
```

*Further workarounds*

It turns out that splitting the interval is not even needed, just the assumption:

```
Integrate[
 f[y] DiracDelta[a - y]*DiracDelta[y - b],
 {y, -Infinity, Infinity},
 Assumptions -> a < b]
(*  0  *)
```

And the specific integral works without splitting if the interval is infinite:

```
Integrate[
 DiracDelta[1 - y]*DiracDelta[y - 5],
 {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]
(*  0  *)
```

Comment: How about `Integrate[  DiracDelta[y - 1]*DiracDelta[1 - y]*DiracDelta[y - 5], {y, 0, 10}]` which returns the input, but `Integrate[  DiracDelta[y - 1]*DiracDelta[1 - y]*DiracDelta[y - 5], {y, 0, 3}]` and `Integrate[  DiracDelta[y - 1]*DiracDelta[1 - y]*DiracDelta[y - 5], {y, 3, 10}]`result in zero? Up to the documentation, the product `DiracDelta[y - 1]*DiracDelta[1 - y]*DiracDelta[y - 5]` is not defined because the supports of `DiracDelta[y-1]` and `DiracDelta[1-y]` are the same set `{1}`?

Comment: In addition. `Integrate[
 DiracDelta[y - 1]*DiracDelta[1 - y]*DiracDelta[y - 5], {y, 0, 3, 10}]` produces `0` though, according to the documentation, the integrand is not defined.

Comment: @user64494 Comments are not for asking new questions.  SE has a mechanism for that.

Comment: MichaelE2(@ does not work.): This is not a new question, but a slight midification of the question under consideration, where your sggestion leads to a meaningless result.

Comment: @user64494 A modification of a question is a new question, and I explicitly posit $A<B$. We'll have to wait to see whether the OP meant to include that condition but left it unstated.

Comment: MichaelE2(@ does not work.): Sorry for the typos in my comment. Of course, it should be "modification" and "suggestion" in the above.

Comment: @user64494 Another way to look at it is that what we have here is a case that looks like user error.  What you have looks like a *Mathematica* error. Those are very different questions, imo, in addition to the surface differences (two deltas vs. three, etc.).

Comment: MichaelE2(@ does not work.): The state of affairs is the following: `Integrate[  DiracDelta[y - 1]*DiracDelta[1 - y]*DiracDelta[y - 5], {y, 0, 3, 10}]` produces a wrong answer. That's all.

Comment: @user64494 And this has nothing to do with the problem at hand.  That's all.